# Operaciones matemáticas dentro de Switch

Tags: javascript, switch

El programa funciona, pero en la parte de suma en lugar de hacer la suma concatena las cifras

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ejercicio 13</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Ejercicio 13 Estructuras selectivas</h3>
                <label for="text">Número 1</label>
                <input id="num1" type="text">
                <label for="text">Número 2</label>
                <input id="num2" type="text">
                <label for="text">Operación</label>
                <input id="Operación" type="text">
                <input id="Calcular" type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="cartel()">
        <script type="text/javascript">

               function cartel(){                  
                  const num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
                  const num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;

                  const operacion = document.getElementById("Operación").value;

                  switch(operacion){
                  case 'S':
                   alert("La suma de los números ingresados es: "+num1+num2);
                  break;
                  case 'R':
                   alert("La resta de los números ingresados es: "+num1-num2);
                  break;
                  case 'M':
                   alert("La multiplicación de los números ingresados es: "+num1*num2);
                  break;
                  case 'D':
                      if (num2 != 0){
                       alert("La multiplicación de los números ingresados es: "+num1/num2);
                      }else{
                           alert("No se puede realizar la división, revise segundo valor");
                      }
                   break;
                  default:
                         alert("Letra desconocida");
                  break;
                  }
                }
           </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Los valores de `num1` y `num2` son texto. Lo que puedes hacer es usar [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) para convertir esa cadena a un número entero y no tener problemas para hacer tus operaciones. Adicionalmente puedes leer [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_for.asp#:~:text=When%20used%20together%20with%20the,elements%20used%20in%20the%20calculation.), para que te quede claro el uso del atributo `for` en HTML, ya que en tu anterior pregunta también lo estás aplicando mal.

Comment: ¿Y en dónde aplico la función parseInt() en este programa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te mencioné en el comentario, puedes hacer uso de la función global [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) para convertir la cadena a un número. En caso de que la cadena no sea un número válido, el valor será [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN). Luego puedes evaluar que ninguno de los dos números sea `NaN` para evitar algún error al momento de hacer la operación.

```js
function cartel() {
  const num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  const num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);

  if(!num1 && !num2) {
    alert("Introduce un número");
    return;
  }

  const operacion = document.getElementById("operacion").value.toUpperCase();

  switch (operacion) {
    case "S":
      alert("La suma de los números ingresados es: " + (num1 + num2));
      break;
    case "R":
      alert("La resta de los números ingresados es: " + (num1 - num2));
      break;
    case "M":
      alert("La multiplicación de los números ingresados es: " + num1 * num2);
      break;
    case "D":
      if (num2 != 0) {
        alert("La multiplicación de los números ingresados es: " + num1 / num2);
      } else {
        alert("No se puede realizar la división, revise segundo valor");
      }
      break;
    default:
      alert("Letra desconocida");
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Ejercicio 13 Estructuras selectivas</h3>
<label for="num1">Número 1</label>
<input id="num1" type="text">
<label for="num2">Número 2</label>
<input id="num2" type="text">
<label for="operacion">Operación</label>
<input id="operacion" type="text">
<input id="calcular" type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="cartel()">
```

Comment: Le hice unas pequeñas correcciones al código y funciono. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Considera colocar la solución que encontraste o aceptar como válida está respuesta si te sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Claro el sigo (+) en un cadena va a concatenar lo que sea dentro de esa cadena , lo que deberias hacer es colocarlo dentro de un parentesis.

Ejemplo : "Esto es una cadena y la suma de este ejemplo dara como resultado " + (2+2)

Resultado : Esto es una cadena y la suma de este ejemplo dara como resultado 4

Te dejo [Aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings) una referencia sobre cadena y como manejarla

Comment: En todo caso no realizes las operaciones dentro de una cadena hazlo por separado y solo agregas el resultado a la cadena  .